# object HTMLInputElement JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, I'm doing a webpage to calculate my school marks but I can't get it to print the result at the input value... Instead, it prints [object HTMLInputElement]

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script>

    window.onload = function () {

        var quran = document.getElementById('quran').value;
        var islamic = document.getElementById('islamic').value;
        var arabic = document.getElementById('arabic').value;
        var english = document.getElementById('english').value;
        var games = document.getElementById('games').value;
        var pc = document.getElementById('pc').value;
        var maths = document.getElementById('maths').value;
        var chem = document.getElementById('chem').value;
        var phys = document.getElementById('phys').value;
        var bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
        var social = document.getElementById('social').value;

        var result = Number(quran) + Number(islamic) + Number(arabic) + Number(english) + Number(games) + Number(pc) + Number(maths) + Number(chem) + Number(phys) + Number(bio) + Number(social);
    }

        function resultFunc() {
            document.getElementById('result').value = result;
        }

</script>
```

And here's the table with the inputs:

```
    <table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>المادة الدراسية</th>
    <th>الدرجة العظمى</th>
    <th>درجة الطالب</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">القرآن الكريم</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">20</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="quran" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">التربية الإسلامية</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">40</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="islamic" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">اللغة العربية</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">60</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="arabic" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">اللغة الإنجليزية</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">60</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="english" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">البدنية</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">20</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="games" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الحاسوب</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">20</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="pc" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الرياضيات</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">80</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="maths" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الكيمياء</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">60</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="chem" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الفيزياء</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">60</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="phys" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الأحياء</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">40</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="bio" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">الإجتماعيات</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">40</td>
    <td data-th="Year"> <input value="" id="social" style="width: 70px;" type="text"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>المجموع</th>
    <th>500</th>
    <th> <input style="width: 70px; background-color: gray;" id="result" value="" readonly /> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="font-size: 20px;">النسبة</th>
    <th></th>
    <th> <input style="width: 70px; background-color: gray;" value="" readonly /> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th> <input onClick="resultFunc()" type="submit" id="submit" value="اضغط هنا لحساب النسبة المئوية" /> </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry for the Arabic words, just look at the code :)

I've even tried to print the result in a cell instead of an input tag, but it gave me a similar error instead of printing the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be due to the calculation occurring during the `window.onload` event.  In order to calculate the values you should be able to move the code from the `onload` event to the `resultFunc` function and it will allow you to calculate the total when you click the button.

```
function resultFunc() {
  var quran = document.getElementById('quran').value;
  var islamic = document.getElementById('islamic').value;
  var arabic = document.getElementById('arabic').value;
  var english = document.getElementById('english').value;
  var games = document.getElementById('games').value;
  var pc = document.getElementById('pc').value;
  var maths = document.getElementById('maths').value;
  var chem = document.getElementById('chem').value;
  var phys = document.getElementById('phys').value;
  var bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
  var social = document.getElementById('social').value;

  var result = Number(quran) + Number(islamic) + Number(arabic) + Number(english) + Number(games) + Number(pc) + Number(maths) + Number(chem) + Number(phys) + Number(bio) + Number(social);

  document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

Also note the reason why you get `[object HTMLInputElement]` is due to the scoping of the variable `result`.  Since you declare `var result` in `resultFunc` the value is immediately lost.  `[object HTMLInputElement]` is rendered, because `window.result` is also a shortcut to the element in the HTML document with the id of `result`.